# AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'is_active' flask application

Tags: python, authentication, flask, flask-login

I am trying to login to my flask application. I have tried debugging but I see no bugs. Registration is working correctly, The app raises validation error when I use wrond details but when I try to log in I get the following error

```
  File "/home/dave/appworld/web-app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/dave/appworld/web-app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/dave/appworld/web-app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/dave/appworld/web-app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/dave/appworld/web-app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/dave/appworld/web-app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/dave/appworld/web-app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/dave/appworld/web-app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/dave/appworld/web-app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/dave/appworld/web-app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/dave/appworld/web-app/flaskblog/routes.py", line 60, in login
    login_user(user, remember = form.remember.data)
  File "/home/dave/appworld/web-app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 158, in login_user
    if not force and not user.is_active:
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'is_active'
```

I have the following `routes.py`

```
from flask import render_template, url_for, flash, redirect
from flaskblog.forms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm
from flaskblog.models import User, Post
from flaskblog import app, db, bcrypt
from flask_login import login_user


@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def home():
    return render_template('home.html', posts=posts)


@app.route("/about")
def about():
    return render_template('about.html', title='About')


@app.route("/register", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.password.data).decode('utf-8')
        user = User(username =form.username.data, email=form.email.data, password=hashed_password)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your account has been created! you are now able to log in', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('register.html', title='Register', form=form)


@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
        if user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
            login_user(user, remember = form.remember.data)
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
        else:
            flash('Login Unsuccessful. Please check email and password', 'danger')
    return render_template('login.html', title='Login', form=form)
```

I have tried running my `run.py` file but I keep getting

```
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'is_active'
```

My `models.py` is as follows

```
from datetime import datetime
from flaskblog import db, login_manager
from flask_login import UserMixin


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email}', '{self.image_file}')"


class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post('{self.title}', '{self.date_posted}')"
```

Comment: I missed that you were already using `UserMixin`, so it is a little suprising to see that error. Did you make sure to restart your server already?

Comment: Did u migrate after using `UserMixin` in your `User` model?

Comment: I have started the server severally. I expected it to be working just fine too.

Comment: @DarkSuniuM I haven't migrated. I am not event using Alembic yet and I haven't touched the models.

Comment: Did u even created a database? By migrate I mean, changing database structure ( in the database ) after using UserMixin

Comment: After adding `UserMixin` and running your migrations (new changes to your database), it should work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

I am too late but if anyone in the future has the same issue then it can be simply fixed by writing your won is_active() fucntion inside class User

```
from flask_login import UserMixin

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
        #code

    def is_active(self):
       return True


    def __repr__(self):
       return " "
```